# The most elegant way to do a calculation on dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe, calculation

I'm a newbie in python.

I have a column in pandas dataframe called [weight].

Which is the efficient and smartest way to redefine securities's weights to sum 1 (or 100%) ? something like the sample calculation below

```
        weight  new weight
        0,05    14%
        0,10    29%
        0,20    57%
total   0,35    100%
```

`df = pd.DataFrame({'Security' : ['ABC','DEF','GHI'], 'Rating': ['AAA', 'BBB','AA'], 'Weight' : [ 0.05, 0.1, 0.2]})`

`print(df)`

```
Security Rating  Weight
   ABC    AAA    0.05
   DEF    BBB    0.10
   GHI     AA    0.20
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can devide weight by sum of weights and get the percentage of weight (`newWeight`):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Security' : ['ABC','DEF','GHI'], 'Rating': ['AAA', 'BBB','AA'], 'Weight' : [ 0.05, 0.1, 0.2]})
df['newWeight'] = 100 * df['Weight'] / sum(df['Weight'])
print(df)

##   Rating Security  Weight  newWeight
## 0    AAA      ABC    0.05  14.285714
## 1    BBB      DEF    0.10  28.571429
## 2     AA      GHI    0.20  57.142857
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `apply` method is a neat way to solve this problem. You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Security' : ['ABC','DEF','GHI'], 'Rating': ['AAA', 'BBB','AA'], 'Weight' : [ 0.05, 0.1, 0.2]})
total = df.Weight.sum()
df['newWeight'] = df.Weight.apply(lambda x: x / total)
```

The resulting DataFrame looks like this:

```
  Security Rating  Weight  newWeight
0      ABC    AAA    0.05   0.142857
1      DEF    BBB    0.10   0.285714
2      GHI     AA    0.20   0.571429
```

If you want to represent these as percentages, you need to convert them to strings, here's an example:

```
df['percentWeight'] = df.newWeight.apply(lambda x: "{}%".format(round(x * 100)))
```

And you get the result:

```
  Security Rating  Weight  newWeight percentWeight
0      ABC    AAA    0.05   0.142857           14%
1      DEF    BBB    0.10   0.285714           29%
2      GHI     AA    0.20   0.571429           57%
```